# What's the cleanest way to reversibly break SQL Server replication?

Tags: sql-server-2008, monitoring, replication

I'm playing around with SQL Server Agent alerts, hoping that I can get some reliable error notifications sent out when our transactional replication breaks.  To test it however, I need to break it.  I have a subscription that's safe to break, but I don't want to have to spend hours reinitializing and delivering snapshots afterward.  Is there an easy, reversible way to break replication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ALTER DATABASE foo SET SINGLE_USER`

Since the SQL agent jobs that perform replication cannot connect to a database in single-user mode, this has the simultaneous result of stopping replication, and disallowing client connections.

Ergo, replication is broken but it can be resumed without re-initializing (the LSN is still good)

Answer (score 0):

What about testing it to perfection in a VM environment and then duplicating it to the real servers. A VM can easily be rolled back to a previous state so you can always start over again.

Comment: Effort.  In our case it's fine to break replication in production for a minute or two, and far less of a cost than duplicating our environment.  I sure wish we had replication in our test environment, though...